# "No module named 'exceptions" error when running Ansible on Ubuntu in WSL and doing an Ansible ping with a host

Tags: ansible

Does anybody know a solution to fix the below error?
I suspect this is because Ansible is using Python3 and the module errors does not exist in this version

```
xx.xx.xx.xx | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_name": "ping"
    },
    "module_stderr": "",
    "module_stdout": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"//.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1532988739.2-140885958960505/ping\", line 44, in <module>\r\n    import exceptions\r\nImportError: No module named 'exceptions'\r\n",
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE",
    "parsed": false
```

Comment: I fixed it by updating ansible from v2.2.0 to v2.7.10

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been opened many times on GitHub.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/6345

Comment: The error was not clear ... I don't understand why the developers don't try to differentiate between the ansible errors and the remote script errors. 
I realized that it is the remote python version that is wrong as explained in the message. The remote host is an ESXi and the default python seems to be ver 3.x

Comment: I agree the error is unclear but that is because every possible error cannot be addressed. It is not practical to expect the developers to account for every possible environment and every possible error.

And in this case, it actually is an Ansible error and a remote script error. Ansible failed to run correctly because it was run as a remote script on a different machine with an unsupported default environment.

Comment: It is expected to let the user know if the error was encountered while running on the remote host or on the controller

Comment: That is already differentiated, even on debug level 0. Ansible is simply a wrapper for SSH so 99% of the errors that happen on the controller involve the connection to the remote host, not the module being run which is clearly stated in an error message. In addition, if you increase the debug level, it becomes apparent where the error was encountered.

Comment: For network devices it is not a wrapper only ...the module code runs on the controller

Comment: Ansible networking is a different beast, but even then, it is sending the same commands as you would manually. Either way, you are ignoring the fact that adjusting the debug level will show more details about where in the play, the error is occurred.

Comment: I am not ignoring anything, you are assuming things about my skills :-)